# Skype not recognizing microphone and camera after suspending the system

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, skype, microphone

I'm having a problem with Skype after the Ubuntu upgrade to the version 18.04. After trying several solutions that I found here, installing and uninstalling Skype, I realized that when I log-out and log-in, the problem is solved. Skype stops recognizing the microphone and the camera only when I close the cover of the notebook and the system is suspended.

Any idea how to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: No idea how to fix it but a vague idea about what may be happening as it sometimes happens with other devices. It's the power management working incorrectly when waking up certain devices. But... Is it only in Skype or affects other apps too?

Comment: Just on Skype. I can use the web version of hangouts without problem :p

Comment: Then it's a Skype's problem which may be hard or impossible to solve because it's proprietary software. Maybe raising a bug report? I don't know where or how though and I don't use Skype.

Comment: Any solution after this much time?

Comment: I'm still having problems with the audio. The "best" solution I found is opening the PulseAudio interface, and changing the value of the volume of the microphone. That triggers some kind of update and at least the audio comes back